# Simple Number Theory question! What is the remainder when 4^999 is divided by 100?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know I'm supposed to use modular arithmetic, but I must be messing up my process somehow. Can someone explain how to do this?

$4^{999}$'s last two digits in other words (What is $4^{999}$'s remainder when divided by $100$)

Comment: One way is to work separately modulo $4$ (trivial) and modulo $25$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
4^6 = 4096 \equiv -4 \bmod 100
$$

so the cycle must repeat every $2(6-1) = 10$ powers of $4$.  Now,

$$
4^9 = 2^{18} = 262144
$$

so the last two digits are $44$.

Comment: Thank you! I'm just learning NT and am rubbish at mod, so this helped a lot. :)

Comment: The Chinese remainder theorem approach is more systematic; my solution here is much more *ad hoc* (but I knew someone would post the CRT solution).  Jack D'Aurizio's solution does not expand on the details of how to construct the solution; look here for a description of how to do so: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem

Comment: I preferred your solution because keep in mind my lack of mod experience, and this is a method I am more familiar with. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 4):

Since $\phi(25)=20$, we have:
$$ 4^{999}\equiv 4^{-1}\equiv 19\pmod{25} $$
while obviously $4^{999}\equiv 0\pmod{4}$, hence by the Chinese theorem:
$$ 4^{999} \equiv 44\pmod{100}. $$

Comment: This helped too!